# Underscore getting values with key of "geom"

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this array of objects.

```
[ { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.81086160022019,50.4619066354793]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.038333333,51.17166667]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.286666667,50.99666667]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.006666667,51.11833333]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.155,50.75333333]}' } ]
```

I want it without the `geom:` leaving me with

```
[ {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.81086160022019,50.4619066354793]},
  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.038333333,51.17166667]},
  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.286666667,50.99666667]},
  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.006666667,51.11833333]},
  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.155,50.75333333]}]
```

Can this be done with underscore?

Comment: _Can this be done with underscore?_: The answer is **Yes.**

Comment: OK. I forgot, this is stack overflow, I should be specific with my question. How can I do this with underscore?

Comment: That is not the problem, you should also show the efforts when asking questin.

Comment: I suggest you go through the underscore docs and learn for yourself what features are available. It's hardly realistic for you to ask a question on SO every time you want to do something, because you can't be bothered to learn a package's features. It's also not a good idea because you will get downvoted over and over, as you should ("question does not show any research effort"). `map` is one of the most basic Underscore routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without `underscore` as well. You just have to loop over array and return `currentObj.geom`. Also, `currentObj.geom` is a string, so you would need `JSON.parse`

```js
var a = [ { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.81086160022019,50.4619066354793]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.038333333,51.17166667]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.286666667,50.99666667]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.006666667,51.11833333]}' },
  { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.155,50.75333333]}' } ]


var result = a.map(function(item){
  return JSON.parse(item.geom);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

As **@Rajesh** stated, there is no need for underscore here, but if you really want to use it then can just do:-

```
var data = [ { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.81086160022019,50.4619066354793]}' },
             { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.038333333,51.17166667]}' },
             { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.286666667,50.99666667]}' },
             { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.006666667,51.11833333]}' },
             { geom: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.155,50.75333333]}' } ];

var vals = _.map(data, function(obj){
   return JSON.parse(obj.geom);
});
```